# How to use #pragma omp task with #pragma omp simd

Tags: c, concurrency, parallel-processing, openmp

I want to write a parallel program that computes a perimeter, area and diagonal of multiple rectangles. The way I thought is to use a functional parallelism to build my program.

First, the perimeter, area and diagonal measures will be parallelized.

In my program, to compute these measures, I'm using `#pragma omp for` to divide loop iterations into threads and `#pragma omp simd` to vectorize the computation. But the problem is that I need to use `#pragma omp task` that represents a non-structured functional parallelism in the code but I don´t know how to use it with `#pragma omp simd`.

I know if I use in the way shown below, I'll be vectorizing the task creation, what makes no sense to SIMD architecture.

If someone could explain how to use `#pragma omp for`, `#pragma omp simd` and `#pragma omp task`, I'll be very grateful.

My code:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<omp.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<time.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 4

/**
 *  This program computes three measures of a rectangle
 *  1. Perimeter ==>    P = 2B + 2H
 *  2. Area      ==>    A = BH
 *  3. Diagonal  ==>  D^2 = B^2 + H^2
 * 
 * 
 * 
 * You must use these 4 directives: parallel, for, simd, task
 */

enum {
    BASE = 0,
    HEIGHT = 1,
};


#pragma omp declare simd
double compute_perimeter(double base, double height){ return (2 * base + 2 * height); }

#pragma omp declare simd
double compute_area(double base, double height){ return (base * height); }

#pragma omp declare simd
double compute_diagonal(double base, double height){ return (sqrt((base * base) + (height * height))); }

double ** generate_rectangles(size_t n){
    double ** rectangles = (double **)malloc(n * sizeof(double *));

    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        rectangles[i] = (double *)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
        for(size_t j = 0; j < n; ++j) rectangles[i][j] = rand() % 100;
    }  

    return rectangles;
}

void destroy_rectangles(double ** rectangles, size_t n){
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) free(rectangles[i]);
    free(rectangles);
}

int main(){

    srand(time(NULL));

    size_t n = rand() % 100000;

    double * perimeters = (double *)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    double * areas = (double *)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    double * diagonals = (double *)malloc(n * sizeof(double)); 

    double ** rectangles = generate_rectangles(n);


    #pragma omp parallel for simd num_threads(NUM_THREADS) schedule(static)
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        #pragma omp task
        {perimeters[i] = compute_perimeter(rectangles[i][BASE], rectangles[i][HEIGHT]);}
        #pragma omp task
        {areas[i] = compute_area(rectangles[i][BASE], rectangles[i][HEIGHT]);}
        #pragma omp task
        {diagonals[i] = compute_diagonal(rectangles[i][BASE], rectangles[i][HEIGHT]);}
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) printf("rectangle %d:\n base = %lf, height = %lf, perimeter = %lf, area = %lf, diagonal = %lf\n\n", i, rectangles[i][BASE], rectangles[i][HEIGHT], perimeters[i], areas[i], diagonals[i]);

    free(perimeters);
    free(areas);
    free(diagonals);
    destroy_rectangles(rectangles, n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tasks are generally expensive to create. The thing is the goal of a parallel code generally to be faster and not just to use more resource. Expressing more parallelism does not means the target program will be faster : if the current amount of parallelism is enough, it may even be slower due to the overhead. By the way, you can use 3 loops and put each loop in a task. Additionally, flatten array are significantly faster than jagged arrays (ie. `double **` is not efficient).

Comment: Regarding the SIMD instruction, it does not make sense to me to put the `for simd` on a loop having tasks because SIMD means "single instruction multiple data" while tasks are meant to execute multiple sets of instructions that can be executed in parallel, not to mention tasks operate at a much bigger granularity. If you really want to use tasks, then you need to use tiling so to move the `for simd` in the inner-loop from the outer-loop running tasks. I doubt this will be faster since `n` is already large enough for all mainstream machine.

Comment: Last but not least, your current loop should not be vectorized on most architecture at least because of the jagged arrays, so the `simd` clause is certainly useless. On x86-64 CPUs not supporting AVX-512, there is no SIMD instructions to read/write things like `rectangles[i][BASE]`. Since AVX-512, there are gather instructions but they are not much faster than scalar one on current Intel CPUs and can actually be much slower on future AMD ones coming soon. On ARM, AFAIK, there is no such NEON instruction either. I think SVE supports that but most ARM chip does not support SVE yet anyway.

Comment: @JérômeRichard thanks for explanation man, I really appreciate that. I'll change my code to these flat arrays and change the way I'm using OpenMP constructors. Once more, thanks for help.

Comment: Also, the expand on Jerome's comment re. `rectangles[i][BASE]`, advancing along a _row_ is _contiguous_ [and therefore more likely for simd], so, if you can, transpose your matrices and increment with `rectangles[BASE][i]` instead.